# move header image to right side

Tags: html, css, css-float

Okay folks, I'm using HTML and CSS here and I'm trying to get my logo that I've got in my header to the right hand side but when I **float:right;** the blue background doesn't stay.
any idea what I could be doing wrong?

HTML

```
<header id="header">
<img id="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo.png" title="Mystery"/>
</header>
```

CSS

```
#header {
background-color: #9CF; }
#logo {
float:right;}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
#header { text-align: right}
```

Remove the float from the img.

Alternatively you can just as easily add a height to your header to fix the issue with the float:

```
#header {background-color: #9CF; height: 100px} /* example height */
#logo {float:right;}
```

Demo of this: http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/y2pX6/1/

Comment: Here is a simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/Tcp78/ You need to remove the float.

Comment: Oops, yup that's working for me now. I'll accept this one as it seems the more "proper" way to do it

Comment: Thanks!  I'm not sure it is the most proper, but it does answer your question and is simple.

Comment: Good solution if you don't want anything else in your header.

Comment: @dsundy that is not accurate, you should have written if you don't want anything else right aligned in the header but all the same one can quite easily work with it even with other items.

Comment: God dammit I'm such a noob. You're actually correct there dsundy! I'll be accepting your answer now

Comment: You could also just add a height to the header and your float works fine.  I've added this to my answer too..  Your question is kind of vague in that it can have multiple solutions.

Comment: I apologise, my question wasn't as clear as it could have been. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @user182 there is no reason to apologize.  There are many answers that will work for you so you just have to pick the best one for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can put `overflow:hidden` on `#header` or do a clearfix hack.

Nicholas Gallagher's micro clearfix:

```
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

/**
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */
cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to make it so complicated. You can just add a height to the header.

Answer (score 1):

Just add:

```
#logo {
    float:right;
    /*This is important as inline elements like img are inmune to float*/
    display: block;
}
```

If that causes any problem to your layout, you may try also:

```
#header {
    background-color: #9CF;
    /*Part of a classic layout hack*/
    overflow:hidden;
}
```